# Dictionary element-wise operations in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia, elementwise-operations

I would like to broadcast an operation to all values of a dictionary. For an array, I know I can broadcast an element-wise operation using:

```
julia> b1 = [1, 2, 3]
julia> b1./2
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.5
 1.0
 1.5
```

What is an efficient way of broadcasting the same operation to all values of a dictionary? Say, for the dictionary

```
a1 = Dict("A"=>1, "B"=>2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An iteration protocol is defined for both keys and values of dictionaries, so you can just do, eg:

```
julia> d = Dict("a"=>1, "b"=>2)
Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1

julia> values(d).^2
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 1
```

If you want to alter the dictionary in-place, use `map!`, eg:

```
julia> map!(x->x^2, values(d))
Base.ValueIterator for a Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries. Values:
  4
  1

julia> d
Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "b" => 4
  "a" => 1
```

However, your function must output a type that can be converted back to the dictionary value type. In my example, I'm squaring `Int` which yields `Int`. However, in the question you are dividing by 2, which obviously yields `Float64`. If the float cannot be converted back to an integer, then you'll get an error.

Note, you can broadcast over keys also, e.g.:

```
julia> f(x) = "hello mr $(x)"
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f.(keys(d))
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "hello mr b"
 "hello mr a"
```

but this can *not* be done in-place, i.e. you can't use `map!` on keys.

Importantly, note that you should *not* instantiate the collection. Indeed, this would be *inefficient*. So avoid constructs like: `collect(values(d)) ./ 2`.

Comment: This leads to my desired output. However, I would like the new values to overwrite the old ones in the dictionary. How do I do that?